# How to add a tooltip to Boundfields in a Detailsview, but only if color of column has changed

Tags: asp.net, tooltip, mouseover, detailsview, boundfield

I have the following code ...

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvApprenticeship" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsApprenticeship" AutoGenerateRows="false" BackColor="#E0E8F0" GridLines="None" CellPadding="2"
    DataKeyNames="ProgramID, ProgramName, OrganisationName, StudyYearID, Workgroup, Pathway, FinishDate" OnDataBound="Apprenticeship_DataBound">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProgramName" HeaderText="Program:" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudyYearName" HeaderText="Study Year:" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="OrganisationName" HeaderText="Apprenticeship:&nbsp;" NavigateUrl="Apprenticeships.aspx" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Workgroup" HeaderText="Workgroup:" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pathway" HeaderText="Pathway:" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nominal Completion:&nbsp;">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="labEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FinishDate","{0:d/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAddProgramUnits" runat="server" OnClick="AddProgramUnits_Click" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Import the Program Units listed - this may overwrite unit dates. Are you sure?');">Import from Program</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onclick="showhelp('progimphelp');" style="color:White;font-weight:bold;">Help</a>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="LightSlateGray" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

I want to be able to show a tooltip whenever one of the above Boundfields has changed color.

In my C# codebehind, I have code that changes the color of these boundfields depending on certain conditions of the data. This is working fine.

But what I want is to be able to give the users a tooltip when ever they hover their mouse over these Boundfields and ONLY if that field is coloured differently, in my case

> color.Yellow

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the color to yellow in the DetailsView `DataBound` event based on some criteria, you can set the tooltip in that same block:

```
DetailsViewRow.Cells[indexofyellowfield].ToolTip = "some help from code-behind";
```

Comment: Thank you! Something so simple. I had no idea about that property.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but is there a way to add css to the tooltip,

Comment: @CosmosBanda search the site or ask your question separately...we don't really answer unrelated questions in the comments to an answer of a different question.

Answer (score 3):

And to answer my own question, with something else I found, which was overlooked: the convert BoundField to TemplateField option.

From this ...

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Claim Type ID" ..etc../>
```

To This ...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Claim Type ID">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblClaimTypeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClaimTypeID") %>' ToolTip="Enter a numerical value that conforms to the UserChoice Policy document (ie: 65 for GAT)."></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClaimTypeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClaimTypeID") %>' ToolTip="Enter a numerical value that conforms to the UserChoice Policy document (ie: 65 for GAT)."></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="itClaimTypeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClaimTypeID") %>' ToolTip="A numerical value that conforms to the UserChoice Policy document (ie: 65 for GAT)."></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is sweet, because in the Design mode of ASPX, you can select your DetailsView, select the Edit Fields option and select the fields that are BoundFields and convert them straight into TemplateFields. The beauty with that, is that it converts the BoundFields to neat Labels or TextBoxes allowing you to directly code in a ToolTip property! And no code behind! Microsoft got something right there for once.