# jQuery tool tip for bound field in ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView and one of the boundfields I would like to use a tool tip for but when I use it, it gives me the `error: attribute "tooltip is not a valid attribute of element boundfield`. I have the JS enabled; I just want to have the letters NP show up with the jQuery tool tip when it's on the column or even just the header of the column which is even easier. How can I avoid this error?

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="NP" HeaderText="NP" SortExpression="NP" tooltip="np" />
```

Comment: Similar discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647967/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-boundfields-in-a-detailsview-but-only-if-color-of-colum

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it... the workaround is using a TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NP">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NP") %>' ToolTip ='<%# Bind("NP") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```